# change html preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, preventdefault

I have a weird recursive situation.

I am changing some HTML inside a element with a small widget and HTML5 contenteditable.

I binded on that element some events such as:

> $('.myelement).on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved DOMCharacterDataModified', ..

Those events trigger some AJAX call that on success also modifies the same element.

> $('.myelement').html(new_value)

But the thing is, this also triggers those binded events on the element. And then i get a unstoppable ajax recursion.

Is it possible to do something like

> $('.myelement').html(new_value).preventDefault()

as in, don't trigger any of the binded events triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can unbind the handlers while you update the element, or set a flag while updating and check for that flag in the handler and do nothing.

Comment: Thank you SLaks! Will have to wait 7 more minutes to accept your answer